# Why does the audio output not change automatically?

Tags: audio, graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi

Usually on a PC if someone were to connect a device such as a headset, then it would change the output, and vice-versa. Why does this fail to happen with my setup? I've tried checking the normal Windows sound options in Settings & Control Panel, along with the Realtek software, but there's no option for this.

I've only had this issue on my current setup so I assume there's a conflict between my motherboards built-in audio processor, and the graphics card in which I use HDMI to output video and audio. (Never had this issue with HDMI before so it isn't that.)

OS: Windows 10 Pro N
GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 750 Ti (NVIDIA).
CPU: Ryzen 5 1600 Hex Core.
MOBO: Gigabyte B450M DS3H.

Comment: Does Windows detect a new headset when plugged in your Realtek card? If it does not add a new device, then Windows 10 will not switch automatically if another device is selected as the Default Audio device. (ex. HDMI) Selecting a USB headset as default and unplugging it will revert back to HDMI, and back to it automatically when plugged back in. With 3.5mm it isn't always possible.

Comment: This is usually a feature of the sound card drivers themselves. If you are plugging headphones into your monitor, which is getting audio over HDMI, then it may well not be reporting it to your graphics card or operating system. Where are you connecting this new device? To your onboard (realtek) connectors or into the display/monitor? If it doesn't work between the various onboard connectors then I'd be more curious as those often do sense removal/insertion of connectors, I would not expect the same on a monitor connected via HDMI.

Comment: @NatsuKage - In the Sound menu it's already identified as Realtek HD Audio Output, regardless of whether a 3.5mm device is connected or not. And it doesn't matter whether that is the default or not, either way it doesn't change. I'm not using a USB headset, just 3.5mm. I've tried combining the front and rear outputs in the Realtek options and neither fix it.

Comment: @Mokubai - I am connecting a headset to the PC itself (3.5mm), this has worked with previous hardware setups where it usually outputs to a monitor over HDMI from the graphics card, but not this setup for some reason.

Comment: @Ryszmarine - This sounds like your drivers are incorrectly installed. Have you installed the latest ones from Gigabyte? https://www.gigabyte.com/ca/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver

Comment: @NatsuKage - I attempted to update my drivers for both my Graphics card (which did nothing), and my motherboard just now, which caused the Audio Output option to always display "Not plugged in" regardless of whether my headset is plugged in. So it just made the it unusable now lol.

Comment: Sorry to hear that... have you restarted your PC since? If this doesn't restore functionality, you can restore the last functional driver in the Device Manager. Double click on the realtek audio output in the sound section, select the driver tab and restore driver.

Comment: @NatsuKage - I restarted after both updates, that didn't fix it and I couldn't roll back the drivers. However, what I did find is that the rear port works fine and the output can automatically change when the headset is plugged into the rear port, but not the front. I'm not sure why this is the case, maybe I plugged the connector for the front port into the motherboard improperly (somehow as they only go in one way). I will check when I next restart.

Comment: It is possible your front audio panel is defective on your casing. Either that or you have the incorrect drivers (improbable) or the connector is plugged incorrectly. Use the Realtek audio manager to see if it detects the headphone rather than windows.